# if child div exists bind event, if it does not then don't bind

Tags: jquery

I've just started learning jquery so please go easy.

I'm trying to create a slide out menu that when you click a button, the menu slides out showing the menu, when a menu item has been clicked the sub-menu relating to the selection will slide out and replace the existing menu but i'm stuck on a certain part. At the moment when you click on a list item, my jquery code is preventing the link being processed and instead shows the sub-menu which is correct but once you get to the end and there's no more sub menus the links don't work.

What i'm trying to achieve is if .menu ul li has a child div called sub-menu then prevent default, if it doesn't have a child div called sub menu then leave it alone.

I've searched all day and I've only started learning this last week.

Here's the html

```
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="one">1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="two">2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="two-one">3-1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="three">3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="three-one">3-1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="three-two">3-2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="three-two-one">3-2-1</a></li>
          </ul
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="four">4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here's the jquery part i'm stuck on

```
$('nav ul li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: `if ($(this).find(".sub-menu").length) { //Has submenu`

Comment: You could remove the `preventDefault()` and just have a `#` in the href. Then those links that should work would have a url (not #)

Comment: Thanks for coming back so soon, Sergio I can't just have # in the href as i do not control this. timeJV I think i understand part of your code, if i understand it correctly it's saying search through the nav ul li and look for a class with the name sub-menu, I also understand the .length counts the characters but i don't know what to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector):

```
$('nav ul li:has(.sub-menu)').click(function(e) {

});
```

As a suggestion for performance, I recommend binding a delegate handler to the `nav` element, and dropping the unnecessary `ul` in the selection. You probably also meant to search within the matched element, rather than toggling *all* `.sub-menu` elements:

```
$('nav').on('click', 'li:has(.sub-menu)', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Hi zzzzBov, I've tried your code and it works to some extent but i've got an issue with is skipping sub-menus in between the first sub-menu  and the final link. At the moment if i click a link, it won't go through each sub-menu at a time, it will just skip to the end?

Comment: @Dan, I suggest creating a [reduced test case on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show what you're having issues with. I haven't actually tested this code, it's just an example to get you started.

Comment: I've created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/12/ you'll notice it skips the selection and goes straight to the end.

Comment: @Dan, it's toggling the class on *all* `.sub-menu` elements within the `li`. You probably want to use `$(this).children('.sub-menu').toggleClass('open')` instead.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/13/ and it now goes up 1 level but when you click the next link it goes back as it toggle off the class="open". Thanks for your help so far

Comment: it's almost there, i've just changed toggleClass to addClass and it goes through fine, it's just the final links that won't work, here's the update http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/14

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good but this can help:

```
if( $('#element').find('*').length > 0 ) {
  // Do something
  $('#element').click( function () { } );
}
```

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

You con achieve the same using `children()` instead of `find('*')`.

http://api.jquery.com/children/